# Get the cache directory of another application

Tags: android

I'm working on an Android App where I list the path and the size of the cache directory of all apps.
I have written a bit of the code already but now it crashes and i don't know whats wrong.

```
Context context = createPackageContext(p.applicationInfo.packageName, Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE);
items.add(p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString() + ": " + context.getCacheDir().getName());
```

p is the PackageInfo of the File and items is an ArrayList.
A NullPointerException causes the crash.
I hope someone can help me!

**EDIT:
Here is the LogCat:**

```
12-15 02:34:14.507: W/dalvikvm(10789): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e34300)
12-15 02:34:14.511: E/AndroidRuntime(10789): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-15 02:34:14.511: E/AndroidRuntime(10789): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.alexnavratil.test/com.alexnavratil.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Requesting code from app.test.com (with uid 10075) to be run in process com.alexnavratil.test (with uid 10104)
```

I hope this is enough. The full LogCat is very long.

Comment: The answer is given to you - you are trying to run a installed app that has a different user id other than your own app hence the crash! If you are rooted, and invoke `su` it may work.. but as *normal* non-root user - am afraid...

Answer (score 0):

Normally other apps-data-directories are protected by the android opereating system. 
I am not shure, if a none rooted android app is allowed to read other apps app cache.

To clear the app cache there are the manifest-permissions [CLEAR_APP_CACHE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CLEAR_APP_CACHE) and [DELETE_CACHE_FILES](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#DELETE_CACHE_FILES)

Comment: But there are some cache cleaners in the play store and they also have access to the cache directory. I want to delete the cache of each installed app except the system apps but how?

Comment: i already set this permissions. I think it's crashing because i can't run an app inside my app. I think it's the wrong code but i don't know how to get the cache directory. But i think its just Android/data/<packageName>/cache. I will try this method.